# Node.js: meeting is not defined

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am using ejs and trying to fetch some data in frontend but i says: meeting is not defined, anyone can guide me how to fix it.

> complete controller  paste.ofcode.org/ugq8gAVPUUd6W4xRZTpu4A
>
> Note data is already showing into a table which is in tabs and i wants
>   to show it a ta another place which i show below the ejs code,

ejs code:

```
  <% meeting.subjects.forEach(function(subject){ %>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
           <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 pending-task-btn">
                  <span href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg dashboard-icon" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                       <p style="padding-top: 15px; font-size: 25px;
                                                        font-weight: bold;"><%= meeting.subject %></p>
                             <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">date</p>
                               <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">Upcoming</p>
                          </span>
                       </div> 
                 </div> 
             <% }) %>
```

nodejs controller code:

```
        var meetingJson = function (req, res) {
      req.selectSortColumn = function (sortColumn, sortDir) {
          switch (sortColumn) {
             case 0 :
                 return {'subject': sortDir};
             case 1:
                 return {'location': sortDir};
             case 2:
                 return {'date': sortDir};
             default:
                return {'subject': sortDir};
         }
     };
      dataTableUtil(req, function (options) {
         //search, search query for word search
         var search = options.search || '.*';
         var findCriteria = {};
         var searchCriteria = [{
            $or: [
                {'subject': {$regex: search, $options: 'i'}},
                {'location': {$regex: search, $options: 'i'}}
            ]
        }];

        findCriteria['$and'] = searchCriteria;
        findCriteria.attendees = {$elemMatch: {user: req.user._id}};
        //set find criteria based on the type of the meeting
        if (req.params.type == 'past') {
            findCriteria['$and'].push({
                $or: [
                    {date: {$lt: moment().startOf('day')}},
                    {status: 'completed'}
            ]});
        } else {
            findCriteria.date = {$gte: moment().startOf('day')};
            findCriteria.status = 'upcoming';
        }
        //get the meeting records and its count.
        async.parallel({
            data: function (cbListJson) {
                getMeetings(req, options, findCriteria, cbListJson);
            },
            count: function (cbListJson) {
                getMeetingsCount(req, options, findCriteria, cbListJson);
            }
        }, function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                logger.error(err);
                res.json({error: true});
                return;
            }

            //create records of meeting in the format of data table.
            createMeetingRecords(req, results, function (err, responseJson) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(err);
                    res.json({error: true});
                    return;
                }
                res.json(responseJson);
            });
        });
    });
  };
```

where the backend data is already showing from controller:

```
                               <div role="tabpanel">
                            <!-- Nav tabs -->
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Upcoming</a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Completed</a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <input type="hidden" id="pdfUrl" value="<%=pdfUrl%>">
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active fade in" id="tab1">
                                    <table class="display table" id="meeting-upcoming-table">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                Subject
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Location
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Date
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Action
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>


                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab2">
                                    <table class="display table" id="meeting-past-table">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                Subject
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Location
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Date
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Action
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab3">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <input type="hidden" id="taskUserId" value="<%=currentUser._id%>">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                            <label for="status" class="control-label">Status</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="status">
                                                <option value="pending" selected>Pending</option>
                                                <option value="completed">Completed</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <%if(isAdmin){%>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                                <label for="status" class=" col-md-12">User</label>

                                                <select class="form-control col-md-12" style="width:100%" name="taskUser" id="taskUser">
                                                    <option  selected value="all">All</option>
                                                </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <%}%>
                                    </div>

                                    <table class="display table" id="task-table">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                Type
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Note
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Due Date
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                    Task For 
                                                </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Actions
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: You have to passing your `meeting` object or data or array, in your `res.render`

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula   should ou prefer to tell me what i have to do

Comment: I think you should to update your question and add your backend code to render this `.ejs`

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula  this is complete controller paste.ofcode.org/ugq8gAVPUUd6W4xRZTpu4A

Comment: So, now, where is the function you called to render your `.ejs`, then i can see that function. I need the function name.

Comment: oh okay i have render it from backend can u suggest me how can i render it bcoz m new in it

Comment: Can you give me the endpoint you call: localhost:3000/yourpage or what the link. You call url like this: `yoururl:3000/list`

Comment: http://localhost:3000/meeting/list#

Comment: You can see function `renderListOfMeetings` in your code that was you provide. There's no `meeting` object in there. You can add it like an example in there.

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula its already present here "title: 'Meetings',"

Comment: title is string, not an obect like you forEach on your ejs. You have to pass your meeting object. List of your meeting

Comment: "meeting: meetingList," but nthing happens, can u provide the exact answer so i can mark it correct

Comment: I Will do it later. Because I am on the way now

Comment: I've been add my answer, you can try it and if you got some error, please tell me the console.log of meetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only one reason why your `meeting is not defined` it's because you're not passing it in your render when you send the response to the client.

**‍ You can try** this code below , **you can copy** it and change your `renderListOfMeetings` function:

```js
var renderListOfMeetings = async function (req, res) {
  try {
    checkRoles(req);
    const meetings = await Meeting.find({});
    console.log(meetings);
    res.render('meeting', {
        title: 'Meetings',
        pdfUrl : config.pdfUrl,
        isAdmin : req.roleAdmin,
        sectionBCommittee: [],
        meetings: meetings
    });
  }catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
    // do some stuff here, send error or some stuff
  }
};
```

After that, in your `ejs` make sure it's looks like this code below:

```
<% meetings.subjects.forEach(function(meeting){ %>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 pending-task-btn">
      <span href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg dashboard-icon" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
          <p style="padding-top: 15px; font-size: 25px;
                                            font-weight: bold;"><%= meeting.subject %></p>
                <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">date</p>
                  <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">Upcoming</p>
              </span>
          </div> 
    </div> 
<% }) %>
```

I hope it can help you .

Comment: And now, what you see in your console? Because I've been console log in there. What the result you get

Comment: complete console error:
  TypeError: \views\meeting.ejs:220
    218|        <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">
    219|        <div class="carousel-item active">
 >> 220|     <% meeting.subjects.forEach(function(subject){ %>
    221|        <div class="col-xs-3  col-md-3">
    222|        <div class="col-md-2  pending-task-btn">
    223|        <span href="" class="btn btn-success " style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
(node:3972) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated

Comment: error showing at page: 500
Oops ! Something went wrong
We can't find the page you're looking for. Return Home.
TypeError: \views\meeting.ejs:220 218| <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding"> 219| <div class="carousel-item active"> >> 220| <% meeting.subjects.forEach(function(subject){ %> 221| <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3"> 222| <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 pending-task-btn"> 223| <span href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg dashboard-icon" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"> Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Not console in your browser, but console.log in your server.

Comment: same result after "catch(ex) {
          console.log(ex.meetings);
          // do some stuff here, send error or some stuff
        }"

Comment: Are you have some gihtub code? than I can clone it and try it first. If not, you can see my example code above, you have to get meeting list and pass it in your render method and everything will be working fine.

Comment: i have no git, plz el me by seeing it, where m wrong: https://ibb.co/Pw044z1  ,,,   https://ibb.co/ZVPSs1v   ,,,      https://ibb.co/JspQQ8x    ,,,    https://ibb.co/QrSYv5D

Comment: I can't download 1 by 1, you can upload your full code in your google drive maybe, for example. Than I just download and run it.

Comment: full code https://drive.google.com/open?id=1waw5bYIM6XH9u2-t4t759lGPTdrgdErs

Comment: It's not a full code, I mean with packagejson. But If not, I can't do anything. Your project. Then I can npm install and run it

Comment: v10.16.1    ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,its big project and a big db with thousands of people data,,,, u can npm install if any other file needed i can send u

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, I think it's just a simple project. Ok, let's to talk 4 hours from now, because I'm at office now. I will contact you later in your email. And let's do it with remote.